# Blank Table Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having a problem with my database. I have replicated it using adventure works 2014.

I want to show all results where the BusinessEntityID shows more than once. So if a user has been a member of two deparments, their ID will show twice

But this is what I get with the below query.
[image]

```
SELECT Person.FirstName,
       Person.LastName,
       HumanResources.Department.Name AS CurrentDepartment,
       StartDate,
       EndDate
FROM AdventureWorks2014.Person.Person
JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory
    ON HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory.BusinessEntityID = Person.BusinessEntityID
JOIN HumanResources.Department
   ON EmployeeDepartmentHistory.DepartmentID = HumanResources.Department.DepartmentID
GROUP BY Person.BusinessEntityID,
         HumanResources.Department.DepartmentID,
         Person.FirstName,
         Person.LastName,
         HumanResources.Department.Name,
         StartDate,
         EndDate
HAVING COUNT(Person.BusinessEntityID) > 1
ORDER BY Person.LastName, StartDate
```

I remove the Having I do get returned result(the whole table). So I think I know where the problem is not what it is / how to resolve it.

Comment: Please paste your sample input data. it will really help every to understand  the question easily.

Comment: So based on that grouping and that data, what did you expect the query would return?

Comment: I would expect it to return the first screen shot but I get the second

Comment: The query returns nothing because no group has more than one record in it.  As to what query you actually want, you should show us sample data.

Comment: Which records would fulfill the `having` clause? None have a count > 1

Comment: What is your intention when you COUNT `Person.BusinessEntityID`?

Comment: are you sure you dont need `having count () >= 1` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza That is pointless because every group has at least one record in it by definition.

Comment: So I want to show all results where the BusinessEntityID shows more than once. So if a user has been a member of two deparments, their ID will show twice

Comment: I tried this on AdventureWorks2014. The problem is your `HAVING`. There is no record which has a `COUNT(Person.BusinessEntityID)` greater then 1. Without that, your query works (unless you changed the data in those tables)

Comment: @Phil3992 then you need a very different query, that is why you should always include your desire logic, only the result isnt enough. BTW use alias for your table names to make it easy to read.

Comment: GROUP BY Person.BusinessEntityID and HAVING COUNT(Person.BusinessEntityID) > 1 work not together! Group By will generate 1 Record per BusinessEntityID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the grouping separately, what I think you really want is people with more than one record in `EmployeeDepartmentHistory`, e.g.

```
SELECT  BusinessEntityID
FROM    HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory
GROUP BY BusinessEntityID
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
```

I think the most efficient way to integrate this into your current query is by using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT  p.FirstName,
        p.LastName,
        d.Name AS CurrentDepartment,
        edh.StartDate,
        edh.EndDate
FROM    Person.Person AS p
        JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory AS edh
            ON edh.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
        JOIN HumanResources.Department AS d
           ON d.DepartmentID = edh.DepartmentID
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory AS edh2
            WHERE   edh2.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        )
ORDER BY p.LastName, StartDate
```

Comment: This worked perfect. Voting up the other answers for the great help

Answer (score 1):

Im going assume your query works ok and if you dont include the group by will bring all the employees. So you need join with a list of employees with +1 department

```
JOIN (SELECT P.BusinessEntityID  --, COUNT(EDH.DepartmentID)  for debug
      FROM AdventureWorks2014.Person.Person P
      JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory EDH
        ON P.BusinessEntityID = EDH.BusinessEntityID
      GROUP BY P.BusinessEntityID
      HAVING COUNT(EDH.DepartmentID) > 1
     ) as list_of_employees_with_two_or_more
 ON AdventureWorks2014.Person.Person.BusinessEntityID =
    list_of_employees_with_two_or_more.BusinessEntityID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Person.FirstName AS FirstName,
           Person.LastName AS LastName,
           Person.BusinessEntityID AS BusinessEntityID
    FROM AdventureWorks2014.Person.Person
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory
        ON HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory.BusinessEntityID = Person.BusinessEntityID
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.Department
        ON EmployeeDepartmentHistory.DepartmentID = HumanResources.Department.DepartmentID
    GROUP BY Person.FirstName,
             Person.LastName,
             Person.BusinessEntityID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)

SELECT Person.FirstName,
       Person.LastName,
       HumanResources.Department.Name AS CurrentDepartment,
       StartDate,
       EndDate
FROM AdventureWorks2014.Person.Person
INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory
    ON HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory.BusinessEntityID = Person.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN HumanResources.Department
    ON EmployeeDepartmentHistory.DepartmentID = HumanResources.Department.DepartmentID
INNER JOIN cte t
    ON Person.FirstName = t.FirstName AND
       Person.LastName  = t.LastName  AND
       Person.BusinessEntityID = t.BusinessEntityID
```

Comment: Use `BusinessEntityID` you can have multiple employee with same  `FirstName, LastName`. And why dont calculate the `GROUP BY - HAVING` in the cte instead ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza This is a beast of a query :-(

Comment: Why you think Im only wrote the extra `JOIN`  :P. But if you use my query in the cte, the final result is cleaner

Comment: You dont need `JOIN HumanResources.Department` because you dont need the department name,  you can count `department_id` from `department_history`, same you only need `BusinessEntityID` not First or Lastname

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I disagree.  If I read the OP correctly, it wants back all the metadata shown, but restricted to those matching the criteria.  In other words, the CTE just filters the OP query.

Comment: yes, but that metadata is already on the rest of the query. You only need the id to make the filter. I think this would be a simple version and do the same http://pastebin.com/GsTByuum

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza By your own logic, why bother with `AdventureWorks2014.Person.Person` either? The only field retrieved from this is `BusinessEntityID`, which can also be found in `HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory`, so you only actually need this one table to identify the people to include.